# Parse string into object

Tags: javascript

I get the `data` from database, but when I try to parse it with json parse an error accrue indicating this is not a valid json format. (because its values are not in quotation).

> I can not make any changes to `data` valuable & I prefer not to use `replace` if possible!

```
var data = "a,b,c";
data = JSON.parse('['+ data +']'); //error because there is no quotation marks
```

Is there any other JavaScript function that can be used to parse the value of data into json or even array.

Comment: just do `var data = "a,b,c"`, no parsing

Comment: what do you want to get back ?

Comment: can you please check the code again, I fixed the question

Comment: your data is not JSON so you can't use JSON to parse it.

Comment: I want to parse the data into object [{0:'a'},{0:'b'},{0:'c'}]

Comment: my bad what exactly you are looking to do?

Comment: I Want something like this -> [{0:'a'},{0:'b'},{0:'c'}] so I can search through it with underscorejs

Comment: Your question is very unclear, please add real examples of inputs and example outputs.

Comment: ouch...tough downvote

Comment: Something like `"a,b,c".split(',').map(i => ({0:i}))`?

Comment: @oriol Of course you are right,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As said in the comments, your data has not JSON format, so don't try to parse it as JSON.

Instead, it seems it represents a comma-separated list of values. To obtain an array with these values you can use [`String.prototype.split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split).

And then, to wrap each item in an object, you can use [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```
"a,b,c".split(',').map(function(item) {
  return {0: item};
});
```

Simplifying with ES6 [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/arrow_functions),

```
"a,b,c".split(',').map(i => ({0:i}));
```

Comment: Thank you so much, you saved my life :)

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
var data = "a,b,c".split(',');
obj = [];
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
{
  obj.push({'0': data[i]});
}
```

Answer (score 2):

use split() Method to split your string into an array of substrings

```
var data = "a,b,c";
data = data.split(',');
arr = [];

for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
    arr.push({0: data[i]})
}
console.log(data);
console.log(arr);
```